# Homeautomation Dashboard (Tablet / Wallmount)

Tags: linux, android, tablet

I'm a programmer building my own Homeautomationsystem.
I'm looking for some sort of tablet which I can mount to a wall and use to display information as well control things. The software I planed to use is a debian system + opera in fullscreen mode.

However I can not find any tablet which is (relatively) good looking, (relatively) fast and cheap.
There are a lot of android tablet (starting at around 60€) which would suit, but I do not want to pay the overhead of Android, especially since all I need is a browser. Using a debian I could customize boot screens, tune for a really fast boot and so on.

What I need:

- Some sort of Local Network (either LAN or WLAN, maybe using a USB adapter)
- Touchscreen
- Screen size (8" - 12")
- Microphone and Speaker

Nice to have:

- Front Camera
- NFC
- Bluetooth

Not needed:

- Mobile networking (3G/4G)
- Back Camera (since there is a wall anyway)
- Large storage (8 - 16 GByte should be enough)
- Fancy features (Fingerprint, etc)

Price should be as low as possible, because I need about 10 of these.
I have no problem with soldering wires to USB connectors etc or do crazy software stunts to get it working if the tablet is cheap enough.

However is there a tablet which is known to be working with native Linux ?
A industrial PC should be ok too but most of them are either really expensive, or lot awkward.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This [RCA Tablet](https://www.walmart.com/ip/RCA-Voyager-7-16GB-Tablet-Android-6.0-Marshmallow/53990885) usually costs around US$35 at Walmart. Not sure how much it would cost in your country, but the price is much lower than the one you quoted, so maybe it is worth a look.

Its features:

- 7" screen
- Front camera
- Bluetooth
- Works with OTG adapter + USB LAN adapter (I tested it).
- 16GB storage + SD card
- Crazy cheap
- Works pretty well for the price

I couldn't find anyone trying Linux on it, but it has an Intel Atom processor, so it is probably easier than an custom ARM processor.